# closing a window on a timer

Tags: wpf, timer

Functionality that I need: A WPF modeless window needs to close when a window of a third party appliction is closed. Now, I have no problem with the 3rd party app, using some PInvoke for this.

```
using System.Threading;
public partial class MyWindow : Window
{
    public MyWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Timer T = new Timer(CloseCheck, this, 1000, 1000);
    }


    public void CloseCheck(object o)
    {
        MyWindow  w= (MyWindow)o;

        // left out all the PInvoke  condictional code to simplyfy

        w.Close();
    }
}
```

If you run this code it's just a quick way to kill your total application. I think it has to do with threading, but how would I implement things the right way?

Comment: I actually read this one three times. It looks *almost* like a question. But no, no question here, here goes my close vote for the day!

Comment: What do you mean by “kill your total application”? What exactly happens to you?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) to access DependencyObjects from a different thread. You could also use a [`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) instead of a normal timer which encapsulates it.

Also see the [threading model reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx).

Comment: you are probably right. I will try this 1st thing in the morning

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to use [`Window.Dispatcher.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms604732.aspx) to execute the `Close` method on the main UI thread.